# Structuring python classes to determine type of parser to use

Tags: python

I am building a parser in python that needs to:

1. Retrieve a stored HTML page from S3 based on an ID
2. Determine what type of parser to use based on header information in the HTML
3. Return some data from the HTML using the correct parser

How can I create an elegant structure where I request the data from S3 one time, determine what parser to use based on classes I have built, then return the appropriate result?

This is the structure I came up to build the first parser:

```
# / parser.py

from gzip import decompress

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


class Parser:
    def __init__(self, page_id):
        self.landing_page_endpoint = f"https://my_org.org/{page_id}"
        self.parser_name = None
        self.soup = self.get_soup()

    def get_html(self):
        r = requests.get(self.landing_page_endpoint)
        html = decompress(r.content)
        return html

    def get_soup(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.get_html(), "html.parser")
        return soup

    def parse(self):
        """Core method that returns authors and associated affiliations."""
        pass

# /parsers/gregory.py

import json
from parser import Parser

class Gregory(Parser):
    def __init__(self, doi):
        super().__init__(doi)
        self.parser_name = "gregory"

    def parse(self):
        my_parsed_info = 'asdf'
        return my_parsed_info
```

Then I call this with:

```
# views.py
from flask import jsonify, request
from parsers.gregory import Gregory

page_id = request.args.get('page_id')
g = Gregory(page_id)
result = g.parse()
return jsonify(result)
```

My idea is to add a method to each parser class I create such as 'detect_parser' that returns True if it is the correct parser. Then I can make a list of all the parser classes, and go through each one running that method until it is True.

The problem with my current setup is this will call the request to S3 every time I call a class, which is slow and unnecessary. Should I do something where I initialize the overall Parser class once, then pass then into each lower class?

Comment: Your `Parser` class code explicitly gets the HTML whenever an instance is created; it’s within your power to modify `Parser.__init__()` not to get the HTML when an instance is created, but to do it later, perhaps by calling a `parse()` method, or something like that.;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look into a way to register parsers as you create them in your code.  I'd suggest learning about [decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/).

You classes would look something like:

```py
class ParserController:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parsers=[]
    
    def register(self, test):
        def decorated(cls):
            self.parsers.append((test,cls))
            return cls
        return decorated

    def parse(self, page_id):
        html = get_html(page_id)
        for test, cls in self.parsers:
            if test(html):
                parser = cls()
                break
        return parser.parse(html)
         

controller = ParserController()

@controller.register(lambda html: #test to use Gregory parser)
class Gregory(Parser):
    parse(self, html):
        #do stuff

@controller.register(lambda html: #test to use Mark parser)
class Mark(Parser):
    parse(self, html):
        #do stuff
```